# skip auto edit of CompoundBracesBlocks in xtext ?

Tags: xtext

I have DSL that has comments like

```
{***** this is comment
```

When i type comment like `{**` and hit enter xtext autoedit provide `}` to close open `{`, I Can disable it by

commenting `configureCompoundBracesBlocks` method

```
  @Override
        protected void configureCompoundBracesBlocks(IEditStrategyAcceptor acceptor) {
    //      acceptor.accept(compoundMultiLineTerminals.newInstanceFor("{", "}").and("[", "]").and("(", ")"), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
        }
```

But I want to auto close for remain all syntax. Is there any way to crack it down ??

here is my screen-cast how it like when i type comment on my DSL

[image]

Also here is my code what it like to get `configureCompoundBracesBlocks`

```
 public class MyAutoEditStrategyProvider extends DefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider {

            @Override
            protected void configure(IEditStrategyAcceptor acceptor) {
        configureCompoundBracesBlocks(acceptor);
        }
            @Override
            protected void configureCompoundBracesBlocks(IEditStrategyAcceptor acceptor) {
                acceptor.accept(compoundMultiLineTerminals.newInstanceFor("{", "}").and("[", "]").and("(", ")"), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have doubts on that since auto edit is context free. maybe you can customize the command to look at a broader range of the Document and try to detect in which place you are this way

Comment: I dnt get you, I tried like this acceptor.accept(compoundMultiLineTerminals.newInstanceFor("[", "]").and("(", ")"), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
now auto brace not coming for comments, but i needed it on other parts of code

Comment: Bl i meant write your own auto edit strategy

Comment: Any reference link so that I can follow it.

Comment: Bo you have to have a look at the existing ones

Comment: Yup.. that might help me. I am over to it.